# Alamofire Swift-2.0 branch fails with several errors

Tags: swift2, alamofire

I have Xcode7-beta4 and here's the relevant section of my Podfile:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
```

My build is failing with the following errors:

```
/Users/Teja/Projects/Work/CareNarrative/Pods/Alamofire/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift:125:30: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Unmanaged<SecCertificate>)'
/Users/Teja/Projects/Work/CareNarrative/Pods/Alamofire/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift:167:13: Cannot invoke 'SecTrustSetPolicies' with an argument list of type '(SecTrust, [Unmanaged<SecPolicy>!])'
/Users/Teja/Projects/Work/CareNarrative/Pods/Alamofire/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift:173:17: Cannot invoke 'SecTrustSetPolicies' with an argument list of type '(SecTrust, [Unmanaged<SecPolicy>!])'
/Users/Teja/Projects/Work/CareNarrative/Pods/Alamofire/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift:204:17: Cannot invoke 'SecTrustSetPolicies' with an argument list of type '(SecTrust, [Unmanaged<SecPolicy>!])'
/Users/Teja/Projects/Work/CareNarrative/Pods/Alamofire/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift:253:30: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Unmanaged<SecCertificate>)'
/Users/Teja/Projects/Work/CareNarrative/Pods/Alamofire/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift:261:62: 'Unmanaged<CFData>!' is not convertible to 'NSData'
/Users/Teja/Projects/Work/CareNarrative/Pods/Alamofire/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift:272:29: Cannot invoke 'publicKeyForCertificate' with an argument list of type '(Unmanaged<SecCertificate>)'
/Users/Teja/Projects/Work/CareNarrative/Pods/Alamofire/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift:286:35: Cannot invoke 'SecTrustCreateWithCertificates' with an argument list of type '(SecCertificate, Unmanaged<SecPolicy>!, inout SecTrust?)'
/Users/Teja/Projects/Work/CareNarrative/Pods/Alamofire/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift:289:25: Cannot assign a value of type 'Unmanaged<SecKey>!' to a value of type 'SecKey?'
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Screenshot added if it makes it easier to read.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've had a bunch of people report this problem and it has always been due to a configuration issue or an out-of-date branch. The underlying issue has been resolved with Alamofire itself, now we just need to figure out where "your" issue lies. Here's a list of all the things you need to have set properly.

#### Update CocoaPods to the Latest Version

```
cnoon:~$ sudo gem install cocoapods
cnoon:~$ pod --version
0.38.2
```

#### Point xcodebuild to the Latest Version

```
cnoon:~$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 7.0
Build version 7A165t
```

> If this isn't pointing at the Xcode 7 beta 4 version, you can set that in the Xcode 7 preferences under `Preferences` => `Locations` => `Command Line Tools`.

#### Re-run CocoaPods

You may be a few commits out-of-date on the `swift-2.0` branch. Run `pod update` again to make sure you pull in any new commits from that branch.

---

By getting all these settings right, you should be able to resolve your issue. If you continue to have issues, please comment again and I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, My `xcodebuild` preference was incorrect. Fixing it solves the problem!

Comment: I have followed these steps, but unfortunately I still have the same errors. Should I need an additional step?

Comment: After upgrading to Build: `7A176x`, and repeating this process it worked.